# Is there an acceptable way to write reviews of applications on Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is there an acceptable way to write reviews of applications on Stack Exchange sites?

I know that these are usually not welcome on Stack Overflow, and are considered "opinion-based" or "unanswerable", but if I find the features of a particular application very useful and want to share this is there an acceptable way to do this within the Stack Exchange community?

Comment: Nope. ----------

Comment: *"I know that these are usually not welcome on Stack Overflow"* - well, there you go then. Not everything has to be on SO, if you want to wax lyrical about some particular tool you've enjoyed then start a blog (or get a Medium account).

Comment: No. If you want to write a software review, post it on your blog.

Comment: If you could get the authors of the program to post their code on Code Review, you could review the code. But it really just seems like you're trying to fit a square peg in a round hole here.

Comment: If you bought the app through an app store of some kind, you could publish a review there

Answer (score 2):

I call this sort of thing spam. The Stack Exchange network is a network of question and answer sites. That means you ask a specific (to the site) question and you (hopefully) get an answer. A product review does not fit that.  What it does fit is a unsollicited promotion of a product or service.

If you want to make the world aware of some awesome tool or service you can always use a blog post.

Comment: I think it would only be spam if I stood to profit or something like that

Comment: @JosephDoggie Spam on this site is defined as *a unsollicited promotion of a product or service* which a review fits.